# Final Cut Pro X - make multiple movies from a single project

Tags: final-cut-pro

I need to make 4 very similar movies. They share a lot of footage and audio. Is there a way to do this in a single Final Cut Pro project?

Right now I just duplicate the library I want, give it a different name and then go edit it. It would be nice if I could have all the videos related to a project in a single Final Cut project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to duplicate projects inside you Event.

Comment: Please provide specifics on how to do that?

Comment: Select current project and press cmd+d

Comment: *I already know how to do it.*  The author of this question clearly does not ( hence the question ).  A proper answer should be specific and detailed in answering the question.  A single sentence should be a comment not an answer.